# internet explorer 10 default browser in VS(2010)

Tags: visual-studio

There is some way that I can set IE10 as default browser in visual studio?
I'm using VS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to execute site with ie try to execute:
iexplore.exe http://site.com 
or like that

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents=false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName="iexplore";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments=http://www.microsoft.com;
proc.Start();
```

and if you want to make ie default on the system do that by Reg:

Setting for the OS as a whole:

```
[HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Check_Associations"="yes"
"Check_Associations"="no"
```

Setting for Current(ly Logged in Active) User:
( this should override the above one )

```
[HKey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Check_Associations"="yes"
"Check_Associations"="no"
```

GoodLuck...

Comment: It's nice but I want it only for vs10 for web apps.

Answer (score 1):

I found two possible solutions, as you can't in VS2010 set the default browser. I however know it uses the system default (it used IE before with me - now it uses chrome).

1. For each project you work on using browsers, set IE10 as the application to run on F5.
   Open the project properties, chose the Web tab, and set "Start external program" to the IE10 executable.
2. Set IE10 as your system default browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a Web Site project:

1. Right click the Web Site Project file
2. Choose "Browse With"
3. Choose "Internet Explorer"
4. Click "Set as Default"
5. Click "Browse"

This will ensure that every time you start the project (also when you click F5), it will start up using Internet Explorer.